# NameError: global name 'cb' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

I am trying to make a program that calculates the biggest number of objects(nuggets) you can't get with packages of 6-9-20 (I am fairly new to python, i trying using global and nonlocal but it doesn't work either).

```
def nuggets(n):
    x = 6
    y = 9
    z = 20
    for i in range(0,n//x+1): 
        for j in range(0,n//y+1):
            for k in range(0,n//z+1):
                if i*x + j*y + k*z == n:
                    return [i,j,k]
    return None

def cant_buy(n):
    seq=0
    for i in range(n):
        p=nuggets(i)
        if type(p)== list:
            seq+=1
        elif type(p)== None:
            cb=i
            seq=0
    return cb
```

Then this error appears:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    cant_buy(12)
  File "C:\Python33\OCW 6.00\ps2a.py", line 22, in cant_buy
    return cb
NameError: global name 'cb' is not defined

What is wrong? I defined it at the elif statement.

Comment: Your cb is declared/assigned inside the loop/branch statements.
If those paths aren't touched, cb variable isn't ever created.

Comment: Have you tried the code within the function? I tried the beginning of nuggets, and I got this:
>>> x=6
>>> y=9
>>> z=20
>>> range(0,n//x+1)
[0]
>>> range(0,n//y+1)
[0]
>>> range(0,n//z+1)
[0]

I don't think that's what you wanted.

Comment: If you annotate your code line by line with your intentions, we might be able to help you fix them. I suspect that multiple bugs are causing cb to remain uncreated.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code, I got a slightly different yet maybe more clarifying error message. It said:
"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cb' referenced before assignment"

So Python tried to use a variable that was unkown yet.

To declare your variable "cb" before you use it in your loop like so:

```
def cant_buy(n):
    cb = 0  # <---- insert this
    seq=0
    for i in range(n):
        p=nuggets(i)
        if type(p)== list:
            seq+=1
        elif type(p)== None:
            cb=i
            seq=0
    return cb
```

should do the trick.